# How to get statement without set full code using JDT

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-jdt

How to get statement of AST node without set full code (without set class and method/constructor).

for example i have set this code like this:

```
for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

I have create simple code but, it's not working :

```
ASTParser parser = ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS3);
parser.setSource("for(int i=0;i<4;i++) {\nSystem.out.println(i);}".toCharArray());
parser.setKind(ASTParser.K_COMPILATION_UNIT);
final CompilationUnit cu = (CompilationUnit) parser.createAST(null);
cu.accept(new ASTVisitor() 
{
    public boolean visit(ForStatement node)
    {
        System.out.println (node.getExpression());
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: try parser.setEnvironment("", "", null, false) before creating the cu

Answer (score 0):

My suggest u can make some trick by adding code like this :

```
String statement="for(int i=0;i<4;i++) {\nSystem.out.println(i);}";
parser.setSource(("class fo{\nvoid foo(){\n" + statement + "\n}\n}").toCharArray());
parser.setKind(ASTParser.K_COMPILATION_UNIT);
```

Hopefull answer your question.